# Is there a way to enter a Google search so that all terms entered must be consecutive, but not ordered?

Tags: google-search

For example, suppose that as of now, I want to search for the name `Alex Matthew Jacob` in my custom search engine. If I use search without parentheses, I would get a multitude of un-useful pages with people named *Alex*, *Matthew*, and *Jacob* who happen to be far more popular than *Alex Matthew Jacob*.

However, if I do use parentheses, I will end up having to search the same name several times with different word orders because of the various formats of the name in the sites of my custom search engine.

This then begs the original question: Is there a way to enter a Google search so that all terms entered must be consecutive, but not ordered? Or, if not, is there any sort of workaround?

Comment: This question is off topic, however, I thought I would throw this out for you. In Google, enter Alex +Matthew +Jacob. The plus signs require the keywords in all the search results but will not lock it into a phrase.

Comment: I just realized that for two word searches a workaround is typing "'Alex Jacob' OR 'Jacob Alex'", but I would still appreciate some more comprehensive answers.

Comment: To use his example, he means that he's looking for results that include all three names grouped together, but in any order: "Alex Matthew Jacob" or "Matthew Jacob Alex", etc.

Comment: Yup! But I didn't want to type it out :P